# How to remove characters between two specific characters in a String?

Tags: java, string

How to remove characters between two specific characters in a String?

**Example:**

Original String: `"Hello <>Remove this String<> how are you?"`

Modified String: `"Hello <><> how are you?"`

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please read [HowToAsk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then show what you tried

Comment: The description seems a bit imprecise to me. I am not sure what should be done for example on a string like this: `"aaaa<>bbbbb<>ccccc<>dddd"`.

Comment: use StringBuilder to build a new String by using substring from the original String object. I'm sure there should be other ways too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like this:

```
String result = original.replaceAll("<>.*<>", "<><>");
```

Output:

> Hello <><> how are you?

Comment: `"<>.*<>"`  as a 1st argument is shorter and achieves the same result